# Meaning of the Verses

Tags: speech

> Genesis 23:15-16
>
> 15 My master, hear me; the land is worth four hundred shekels of
> silver; what is that between me and you? and bury your dead.
>
> 16 And Abraham listened to Ephron, and Abraham weighed to Ephron the
> silver of which he had spoken in the silver of which he had spoken in
> the ears of the sons of Heth, four hundred silver shekels which passes
> with the merchant.

Reading the verses before the verses above, Ephron doesn't want Abraham to pay for the burial site. He wants to give it for free.

1. Then why did he say, "What is that between me and you ?" What does it mean ?
2. Also, what does it mean "four hundred shekels which passes with the merchant"?

Comment: Which version of Genesis is this?

Comment: Looks like ["Literal Standard Version"](https://biblehub.com/genesis/23-16.htm) is a possible source.

Comment: I presume your question belongs in https://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are far simpler versions available. NIV has " ... four hundred shekels of silver, according to the weight current among the merchants." and NLT " ... according to the market standard." //  Also, many commentaries (eg at [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/23-15.htm)). However, different explanations of "What is that between me and you?" are offered by scholars (though none suggest that 'Ephron doesn't want Abraham to pay for the burial site' ... it's a conversation-lubricating device, at the polite end of the spectrum, unlike "400 shekels. Take it or leave it."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because checking in other versions is easy, and interpretations where reading between the lines is needed belong on Biblical Hermeneutics,SE (though I'm sure Christianity.SE will handle this one).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough (and I didn't know about the other theories of "what is that between"). But we're not really diving deep into hermeneutics here or "applying" the text; IMO it's comparable to, say, someone asking about a turn of phrase in a translation of Homer. The "additional research" I mentioned is not so much exegesis as simply bearing in mind that idioms in translated works often need explanatory footnotes for the casual reader, and all the more so when translating from ancient cultures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be noted that this is one particular translation of ancient dialogue, containing two idiomatic expressions. The quoted English translation might not do the best job of finding a modern English equivalent, but one should not expect such passages to always be transparent to modern readers without additional research.

To understand the context, it helps to know that there's a kind of stilted haggling going on. [Abraham asks](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2023&version=NIV) to buy the tomb "for the full price." Ephron—"sitting among his people" and "in the hearing of all," so, conscious of his public audience—"insisted" that Abraham accept the tomb as a gift. Abraham insisted again that he pay the full market value. Finally, in v. 15 quoted above, Ephron again gives the appearance of offering the tomb for free, but *just happens* to mention its fair price, upon which Abraham promptly weighs out exactly that amount. This kind of elaborate contest of courtesies, offering things that aren't really meant to be accepted so that the other party can have the benefit of refusing, was common in the ancient world and still seen in some cultures.

There are in fact modern English equivalents for these idioms. Ephon says "The land is worth four hundred shekels of silver; what is that between me and you?" A modern equivalent might be "What's 400 shekels [between friends](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what%27s+between+friends)?"

The phrase rather awkwardly translated here as "which passes with the merchant" is, in Hebrew, simply two words, *sahar abar*, which [appear](https://www.blueletterbible.org/niv/gen/23/1/t_conc_23016) to translate more directly as "commercial standard"—that is, "[400 shekels] according to the current weights and measures, as standardized by the merchants."

Comment: Yes, it's negotiations. I couldn't possibly accept the money, but it comes to 9999999.

Comment: I'd prefer that the first 'insisted' had scare-quotes. / This would be better on either Christianity or Biblical Hermeneutics.

Answer (score 2):

> What is that between me and you?

means:

> That amount is unimportant between us.

---

> four hundred shekels which passes with the merchant

means:

> four hundred shekels, as a merchant would agree they weighed (or would value them)